# En MySQL el general_log registra consultas que no pueden ejecutarse?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

En MySQL el `general_log` puede registrar por ejemplo un **UPDATE** en el log a pesar que el servidor este configurado solo en modo lectura `read_only`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la documentación de MySQL [disponible aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html)

El query log funciona para almacenar todas las queries que el gestor de bases de datos recibe; los modos de deshabilitarlo son los siguientes:

1. Usa las variables de sistema globales **general_log y general_log_file**
2. Establece general_log a 0 o también puede ser OFF
3. Poner el valor a 1 o ON equivale a activar el log nuevamente
4. Con la variable general_log_file puedes establecer un nuevo nombre para el log de tus queries

### Desde la documentación

> When the general query log is enabled, the server writes output to any
>   destinations specified by the --log-output option or log_output system
>   variable. If you enable the log, the server opens the log file and
>   writes startup messages to it. However, further logging of queries to
>   the file does not occur unless the FILE log destination is selected.
>   If the destination is NONE, the server writes no queries even if the
>   general log is enabled. Setting the log file name has no effect on
>   logging if the log destination value does not contain FILE.

---

Traducido

> Cuando el registro de consulta general está habilitado, el servidor
>   escribe salida en cualquier destino especificado por la opción
>   --log-output o log_output. Si habilita el registro, el servidor abre el archivo de registro y escribe los mensajes de inicio en él. Sin
>   embargo, el registro adicional de las consultas al archivo no se
>   produce a menos que se seleccione el destino del registro de ARCHIVO.
>   Si el destino es NINGUNO, el servidor no escribe consultas, incluso si
>   el registro general está habilitado. Establecer el nombre del archivo
>   de registro no tiene ningún efecto en el registro si el valor de
>   destino del registro no contiene ARCHIVO.

Comment: Estaba buscando saber que cubría "todas las queries" y me puse a probar, pude observar y comprobar que registra todo; no importa que estén mal escritas, no tenga permisos, o tengan un error sintáctico.

Comment: así es los logs registran todo

Comment: @NicolaStrappazzon en este enlace que te dejo encuentras mas info importante https://www.tecmint.com/mysql-mariadb-security-best-practices-for-linux/